# Updating to Python 3 on Kubuntu 11.04 -- do/should I uninstall previous versions?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

Is this going to break anything?  Is there anything I would need to keep in mind if I do uninstall the older versions?

Comment: There are python programs/frontends that still rely on version 2.X, if you remove those libraries, and decide to install those programs later, you'll need to install them back. Ubuntu does handle dependencies for you though, and typically if you try to remove something that WILL hurt your OS, Ubuntu will warn you.

Comment: I think it a good idea to note that this is a question which can be considered off topic. It may be suggested that this migrate to Superuser or serverfault. Since I would argue that it could be on topic on all three, I will simply recommend that you re-ask this on one of those if it gets closed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would keep both around (and when upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04, I *did*). The problem is that there are still *a lot* of libs which are only in Python 2.x. The good news is that they are decreasing in number/prominence, but too much relies on the older way of doing things to reliably remove it.

If you feel more courageous than I, install a Py3k version and then change the `#!/usr/bin/env python` variable to reflect Py3k and then see what breaks (and I am almost positive something will), but personally, I am perfectly fine using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for a while longer.

I **HIGHLY** recommend that you keep a 2.6 >= Python < 3 version around for a while though, because I will bet money that it will break things if you remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the word of warning!

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove Python 2, Ubuntu will stop working. Python 3 is however a separate package and can be installed in parallell. Since Python3's exe is called 'python3' this doesn't have any negative effects.